# sub sub domains with url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wildcard in the DNS. `*mydomain.com` - it works perfectly. I have the URL rewrite turned on in Apache and it works. This is what I have now:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) user.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

This makes a nice little permalink. Like this

`http://sub.domain.com/user`

My goal is to make the above URL structure to this.

`http://user.sub.domain.com`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To enable you to do this you'll need to add a  wildcard in your .htaccess file for each sub.example.com, so something like *.sub.example.com.

Your file should look somewhat like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.apps\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/apps/%1/$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

You'll have to do this for each one. This is the code that I'm personally using.

Comment: I realize I was not quite clear.  I need the url structure to be http://sub.sub.domain.com The first sub needs to be dynamic. For example this http://sub.domain.com/test.php?url=john  Needs to be turned into this. http://john.sub.domain.com